# overLap Image by another image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am new to iphone development and making an application which chooses an image from existing album. After choosing the image I want to put another View on it, or another icon(acne).

Can anyone tell me how to put another image on existing image by code????

Comment: can be done by adding multiple imageviews but its not memory efficient...if you want ony 2-3 images at a time...this method can help you

Comment: Do you mean by changing the image in the image view, or having two image views and hiding one and showing the other?

Comment: I mean adding an image on other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you want to overlay two views/images you can just do it like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:imageview1];  
[self.view addSubview:imageview2];
```

imageview2 lays on imageview1, because you added it later.

Answer (score 0):

You want to place UIImageView or UIView on the image ?
First you need to create the ImageView with the frame of your choosen image and create another ImageView in the same way as you created first ImageView and add second ImageView to your previous ImageView. if your second ImageView size is equal to the size of first ImageView, you would not be able to see your first ImageView, because it will overlap..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a watermark on your image try this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480));
// This is where we resize captured image
[(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
// And add the watermark on top of it
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Watermark.png"] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:WATERMARK_ALPHA];
// Save the results directly to the image view property
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```